# How do I make a simple API call from a node app to the Intuit QuickBooks API?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, quickbooks

I've set up a simple Node app, with the eventual aim of querying a bunch of QuickBook APIs. I however want to start off by making a single, simple API call just to make sure everything is working. How do I configure my app to do this? I've been using the `intuit oauth nodejs` library, and have set up my express app as follows:

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const { environment } = require('intuit-oauth')
const OAuthClient = require('intuit-oauth')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()

const oauthClient = new OAuthClient({
    clientId:'*****',
    clientSecret: '*****',
    environment: 'sandbox',
    redirectUri: 'https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl',
    logging:true
})


  oauthClient
  .makeApiCall({
    url: 'https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{companyId}/account/1?minorversion=14',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log('The API response is  : ' + response);
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.log('The error is ' + JSON.stringify(e));
  });


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`️ Server listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I've been getting the following error back in my terminal, which suggests this is a token-related issue:

> statusCode=400","detail":"Missing required parameter: access_token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can invoke the `makeApiCall` method, you must execute the [authorization code flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intuit-oauth#authorization-code-flow).

The documentation on NPM also refers to a [sample application](https://github.com/intuit/oauth-jsclient/tree/master/sample).